# ExpressJS pass object to client side (ajax)

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, keystone

I am building so called "Lazy load" where new products load on scroll. In my Ajax (client-side) code I want to interact with an object (locals.data) from server side.
Server side code:

```
exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
let view = new keystone.View(req, res);
let locals = res.locals;

locals.data = {
    products: [],
    categories: [],
    sort: req.query.filterlist
};

.
. . (( querying code here ))
.

view.render('products');
```

Client side code (ajax):

```
let currentPage = 1;
let filterList = data.sort; // <------ I would like to get this from server side!

function addNextPage(){
    currentPage++;

    let parameters = {
        "page": currentPage,
        "filterlist": filterList
    };

    $.get("/products", parameters, function(data) {
        $(".products").append($(data).find('.products .items-box__item'));
    });
}
```

Essentially, I would like to interact with whole locals.data object from server side.

Error I am getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at loadmore.js:4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my own very specific way.
In my HTML (Nunjucks) template I have added an element that stores data within attribute:

```
<div class="variables" sort="{{data.sort}}"></div>
```

and then in my client-side javascript I get an attribute:

```
let filterList = document.querySelector('.variables').getAttribute('sort');
```